# Display text after price in shopping cart - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

how can I modify this code to also display the text after price in shopping cart? Now it only shows it on the archive and product page.
`

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', function() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input([
            'id' => '_custom_text_after_price',
            'label' => __('Text after price: ', 'themedomain'),
    ]);
});

add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id)
{
    $woocommerce_custom_product_text_field = $_POST['_custom_text_after_price'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_text_after_price', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field));
}

function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    global $post, $product;
    if(get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_text_after_price', true )){
        $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_text_after_price', true );
    }
    $price .= ' /'.$text;
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I've used this with some success in the past:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cart_item_amounts_prefix', 10, 3);
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'cart_item_amounts_prefix', 10, 3);
function cart_item_amounts_prefix($amount, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)
{
    $amount = $amount . ' /';
    return $amount;
}
```

perhaps bumping up the priority on your filter?